# How To Determine Bulk Customers (Customers Buying More Than 'N' Items Or So In A Single Transaction) In Python (Sales Data Analytics)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, csv

so I've the following sample dataset:

[image: Sample Dataset]

**Column A: Name**

**Column B: Email**

**Column C: Products**

**Column D: Transaction Date**

I've two objectives:

1. To determine bulk customers (customers who purchase, let's say,
   5 products or more in a single transaction), where each row
   represents a unique transaction with a unique timestamp.
2. To determine from the recurring customers (customers frequently
   making *different* transactions), who all are also bulk customers.

Now, I've already determined the list of recurring customers as follows:

```
n = 15
custmost1 = Order_Details['Name'].value_counts().index.tolist()[:n]
custmost2 = Order_Details['Name'].value_counts().values.tolist()[:n]
custmost = np.column_stack((custmost1,custmost2))
```

Where **custmost** denotes the series tuple clubbed together as an array for customers making frequent purchases with their counts. **Order_Details** is the dataframe I created for the dataset.

Now, I'm at my wit ends to figure out to maintain a count of different products being purchased in a single transaction (with a unique timestamp), and possibly, add it as a separate column in a dataframe.

I don't know if it's a feasible approach or not, but two ways were coming to my mind:

1. One to count the number of commas, so that number of commas+1 will be number of products.
2. To segregate each products into a separate line (which I already did, by the way, for maintaining a total count for a different insight), and checking with timestamp the number of products sold at a given timestamp.

I'd segregated the **Products** as follows:

```
reshaped = \
(Order_Details.set_index(Order_Details.columns.drop('Product',1).tolist())
   .Product.str.split(',', expand=True)
   .stack()
   .reset_index()
   .rename(columns={0:'Product'})
   .loc[:, Order_Details.columns]
)
```

So, in this lieu, I would want someone to guide me as I feel like the aforementioned approaches are actually rather messy.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you give the example data as code so we can copy/paste it to help you out? Or write a setup snippet that is reproducible and generates plausible data. [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) and Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including a small example input data and the corresponding expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you already have a proper `DataFrame`:

```py
>>> df.applymap(lambda e: type(e).__name__).value_counts()
name  email  product  date     
str   str    list     Timestamp    29
dtype: int64
```

(i.e., with columns: `['name', 'email', 'product', 'date']`, where the `'product'` column contains `list` objects, and `date` contains `Timestamp`),

Then you could do this:

```py
bulk_customers = set(df.loc[df['product'].apply(len) >= 5, 'name'])

s = df.groupby('name').size() > 1
recur_customers = set(s[s].index)

>>> bulk_customers
{'PERSON_108', 'PERSON_123'}

>>> recur_customers
{'PERSON_105'}
```

#### Notes

1. I changed the row of `PERSON_125` to be `PERSON_105`, so that there would be one repeat customer. Likewise, I used a threshold of `n_visits > 1` as the criterion for "recurring", but you may want something different.
2. You'd be well inspired to assign a unique ID to each of your customers. This could be based on email or perhaps you already have a customer ID. In any case, using `name` is prone to collisions, plus sometimes customers change name (e.g. through marriage) while keeping the same email or customer ID.
3. You didn't mention over what period of time a customer needs to visit again in order to be considered "frequent". If that is to be considered, you have to be specific whether it is e.g. "within a calendar month", or "over the past 30 days", etc., as each leads to slightly different expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after a bit of extensive brainstorming, I've concocted the following way to do this:

In the original dataset's dataframe (**Order_Details**), I figured out to get the count of commas in each row of the **Product** column, which gave me a frequency of the number of products purchased in a single transaction. The code for that goes:

```
Order_Details['Number Of Products'] = Order_Details['Product'].str.count(",")+1
```

To make sure that I get the names of customers in a sorted order according to the frequency of purchases, I applied the following ***sort_values()*** function:

```
Dup_Order_Details = Order_Details

Dup_Order_Details.sort_values(["Number Of Products","Name"],axis=0, ascending=False,inplace=True,na_position='first')
```

Finally, a filter for those buying more than 'N' products (here, I took N=10, as I wanted this insight, y'all can take 'N' as input if you want):

```
Dup_Order_Details = Dup_Order_Details[Dup_Order_Details["Number Of Products"] >= 10]
```

Then a simple direct display can be done as per your need or you can convert it into a list or something, in case any visualization is needed (which I did).